# f extends uniquely to a continuous f~:M~→M~ where M~ is the completion of M

Tags: real-analysis

$\widetilde M$ is the completion of a metric space, and $\overline M$ is the closure. So do we have $\widetilde M = \overline M$ all the time?

I am working on a question, basically the same as what was asked here, [Suppose $f: M \to M$ is a contraction, but $M$ is not necessarily complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310748/suppose-f-m-to-m-is-a-contraction-but-m-is-not-necessarily-complete).

I want to use the theorem mentioned in webpage https://drexel28.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/extending-uniformly-continuous-functions/, i.e. Theorem: Let $X$ be a subspace of some metric space $\left(Z,\rho_1\right)$ and $\left(Y,\rho_2\right)$ a complete metric space. Then, if $f:X \to Y$ is a uniformly continuous function there exists a unique extension $\widetilde{f}: \overline{X} \to Y$ which is uniformly continuous.

A contraction ($f: M \to M$) is uniformly continuous. So $f: M \to \widetilde M$ is uniformly continuous as well. And we apply the theorem above to get that $\widetilde{f}: \overline M \to \widetilde M$ is the unique extension, which is uniformly continuous. But how do we extend $\overline M$ to $\widetilde M$. In the previous post above in MSE, the answer seems to treat  $\overline M =\widetilde M$. But I am not sure how he proves this.

My idea is that if $x$ belongs to $\overline M \setminus \widetilde M$, then there is a sequence $x_n$ in $M$ converging to $x$. But convergence implies Cauchy, so this tells us $x$ should also belong to the completion $\widetilde M$, a contradiction. So $\overline M \setminus \widetilde M$ is empty, i.e. $\overline M$ is a subset of $\widetilde M$.

$\widetilde M$ is complete by definition, so being a closed subset of a complete set $\widetilde M$, $\overline M$ is complete as well. And this kind of indicates that $\overline M$ is also a completion of $M$, and $\overline M = \widetilde M$.

I do not know where my argument goes wrong. Or it just shows that $\overline M$ is only a subset of $\widetilde M$. And can someone point out how to show that $f$ extends uniquely to a continuous $\widetilde{f}: \widetilde{M} \to \widetilde{M}$ where $\widetilde M$ is the completion of $M$?

Thanks!

As comment points out, "closure only makes sense in relation to an agreed-upon metric space". But the question only says $f$: $M$ $\to$ $M$ is a contraction. So this probably says M is a metric space, and $\bar M$ is $M$. If this is the case, how to solve the question that $f$ extends uniquely to a continuous $\tilde{f}: \tilde{M} \to \tilde{M}$ where $\tilde M$ is the completion of M ?

Comment: It is not so clear what you are asking. To take closure $M$ has to be inside some metric space $Z$, which a priori has nothing to do with $\tilde M$.

Comment: M is the metric space, but not necessarily complete. So I am wondering what is the relationship between its closure and its completion.

Comment: If $X$ is a subset of a metric space $Y$, then $\overline X$ serves as a completion of $X$ when $Y$ is complete. But not always! This is because a *closed* subset of a complete metric space is complete, of course.

Comment: So you mean here we can use closure of M as an example of its completion? And the general relation is that M's closure is a subset of its completion?

Comment: As John pointed out, closure only makes sense in relation to an agreed-upon metric space.  So, for example, $\Bbb{Q}$ is it's own closure (as a subset of $\Bbb{Q}$), but also $\overline{\Bbb{Q}} = \Bbb{R}$ (when we are working in $\Bbb{R}$).

Comment: Yes, so the question only says M is not necessarily complete, f:M to M is a contraction. So this means M is a metric space. And M's closure is just itself, and it is not complete?

Comment: So if M is just the metric space itself, what should be the correct way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are getting tripped up by shortcuts people take when they talk about completions. Technically speaking, we do *not* have $M$ as a subset of its completion $\widetilde{M}$ in general. However, what we *do* have is a map $g:M\rightarrow\widetilde M$ which is isometric and has dense range. This means that $\overline{g(M)}=\widetilde{M}$. Now we usually identify $M$ with $g(M)$, so the closure of $M$ *as a subspace of* $\widetilde{M}$ is indeed the whole space $\widetilde{M}$. It's an abuse of notation but once you are comfortable with the idea it usually doesn't cause confusion.

Once we have made clear that we are considering $M$ as a dense subspace of its completion $\widetilde M$, then it is indeed true that any contraction $f:M\rightarrow M$ lifts uniquely to a contraction $\tilde{f}:\widetilde{M}\rightarrow\widetilde M$.